# LINQ - group specific types of classes

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This question is similar to [LINQ group one type of item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835192/linq-group-one-type-of-item) but handled in a more generic way.

I have a List that has various derived classes. I may have something like this:

```
List<BaseClass> list = new List<BaseClass>() {
  new Class1(1),
  new Class2(1),
  new Class1(2),
  new Class3(1),
  new Class2(2),
  new Class4(1),
  new Class3(2)
};
```

I am trying to use LINQ to semi-sort the list so that the natural order is maintained EXCEPT for certain classes which have base.GroupThisType == true. All classes with GroupThisType should be grouped together at the place that the first class of the same type occurs. Here is what the output should be like:

```
List<BaseClass> list = new List<BaseClass>() {
  new Class1(1),
  new Class1(2),
  new Class2(1),
  new Class3(1),
  new Class3(2)
  new Class2(2),
  new Class4(1),
};
```

**Edit:**  Oops, forgot to say this result is assuming (Class1 and Class3).GroupThisType == true

Comment: @SLaks: Yeah, the only thing I was thinking is GroupThisType would be duplicated and in theory could be different for instances of the same class.  I would create a List<Type> groupTheseTypes, but I don't know the types ahead of time (plugin-type system).  A static variable would probably make the most sense.  It doesn't change your answer.

Comment: ...except if I want it in the base class I can't make it static, otherwise I only have one instance of that variable.  Oh well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
list = list.Select((o, i) => new { Index = i * 10000, Value = o })
           .GroupBy(q => q.GetType())
           .SelectMany(g => {
               if (g.First().GroupThisType)
                   return g.Select((q, i) => 
                       new { Index = g.First().Index + i, Value = q.Value }
                   );
               else
                   return g;
           })
           .OrderBy(q => q.Index)
           .Select(q => q.Value)
           .ToList();
```

The `i * 10000` allows up to 10,000 items from a group to be inserted between any two items.

You can replace `g.First().GroupThisType` with `typesToGroup.Contains(g.Key)`.

Comment: I'm starting to think a more traditional approach would be easier to understand :)  Also, by doing i * 10000 you're limiting how many total items there can be.  I'm guessing i is an int, therefore 2147483647 / 10000 = 214748 max items.  Still WAY over what I would ever have.

Comment: `i` is an `int`, but you can cast it to a `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using two passes: in the first I build a dictionary of all the ones that should group.  In the second I use SelectMany to gather up the elements that don't collate with the collated sequences for the first of any element that does collate.

```
// Build a dictionary of the items that group
var onesToGroup = list.Where(x => x.GroupThisClass)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.GetType())
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.AsEnumerable());

var results = list.SelectMany(x => x.GroupThisClass ?
                             (onesToGroup[x.GetType()].First() == x ? onesToGroup[x.GetType()] : (new BaseClass[]{}))
                                                : (new []{x}));
```

Comment: But it will, I'm not iterating over the dictionary, I'm iterating over the original list and using the dictionary only to find the relevant group.

Comment: It does however rely on GroupBy being in order ... which luckily MSDN confirms is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The OrderBy LINQ method can accept an IComparer generic interface.  You can use this to implement your custom sorting algorithm.  I don't know the default ordering can handle what you are trying to do (it would depend on all the rules you need to implement).  I assume you're classes aren't actually named Class1, Class2 with the ordering in the type name?

HTH.

Comment: He wants to preserve the original order, but move all items of certain types to the position of the first occurrence. It is not possible to do that with an `IComparer`.